Issues integrating Firebase with SwiftUI
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestoreCombineSwift
import FirebaseAuth
struct Message: Identifiable, Hashable, Codable {
    
    @DocumentID var messageId: String?
    let fromId: String
    let toId: String
    let messageText: String
    let timeStamp: Timestamp
    let isImage: Bool
    let isAudio: Bool
    let isVideo: Bool
    let user: User?
    var id = String {
        return messageId ?? UUID().uuidString
    }
    var chatPartnerId: String {
        return fromId == Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ? toId : fromId
    }
    var isFromCurrentUser: Bool {
        return fromId == Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    }
}

struct MessageGroup: Identifiable, Hashable {
    
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var messages: [Message]
    let date: Date
}

extension MessageGroup {
    
    static let MOCK_MESSAGE_GROUP = [MessageGroup(messages: [Message(fromId: "", told: "", messageText: "Wsp dude", isImage: false, isAudio: false,isVideo: false, user: nil),Message(fromId: "", told: "", messageText: "Wsp dude", isImage: false, isAudio: false,isVideo: false, user: nil),Message(fromId: "", told: "", messageText: "Wsp dude", isImage: false, isAudio: false,isVideo: false, user: nil),Message(fromId: "", told: "", messageText: "Wsp dude", isImage: false, isAudio: false,isVideo: false, user: nil),Message(fromId: "", told: "", messageText: "Wsp dude", isImage: false, isAudio: false,isVideo: false, user: nil)], date: Date())]
}


Message.swift:5:8 Type 'Message' does not conform to protocol
'Decodable'
Message.swift:5:8 Type 'Message' does not conform to protocol
'Encodable'
Message.swift:5:8 Type 'Message' does not conform to protocol
'Equatable'
Message.swift:5:8 Type 'Message' does not conform to protocol
'Hashable'
Message.swift:7:6 Unknown attribute 'DocumentID'
Message.swift:17:16 Cannot use instance member 'messageId' within
property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is
available
Message.swift:36:170 'nil' requires a contextual type
Message.swift:36:283 'nil' requires a contextual type
Message.swift:36:396 'nil' requires a contextual type
Message.swift:36:509 'nil' requires a contextual type
Message.swift:36:622 'nil' requires a contextual type

I tried to search it all over StackOverflow but I couldn't find anything similar to my issues.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read How do I ask a good question?, then [edit] your question.

Could be a number of typos, have you tried using var id: String { messageId ?? UUID().uuidString }.
Also fix all typos in your extension MessageGroup eg: told to toId, missing timeStamp etc...
If that does not work, show the code for your User

Also check that the let timeStamp: Timestamp is Codable.

User needs to be Codable too and the computed properties are optional since the uid is optional
